Is there a way to make a POST request for multiple variables?
I'm creating a Blog website as a Capstone Project and I'm trying to get this form to print 3 different variables when I click the submit button, but when I tested the code out, all it does is make the page load without printing anything. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?
I tried using multiple res.render's, grouping all the IF statements into one, and using multiple POST requests, but I either got this "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error or the page loads indefinitely like  the first issue.
Here's my code if it helps:
JS Part
app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {

    const clientName = req.body["fName"] + req.body["lName"]
    const bloggName = req.body["bName"]
    const blogBody = req.body["bEnter"]

    res.render("blog.ejs", { bloggerName: clientName}, { blogTitle: bloggName }, { blogContent : blogBody })
})

EJS Part
 <% if (locals.bloggerName) { %>
      <h1>
        <%= bloggerName %>
      </h1>
      <% } else { %>
        <h1>
          User Name
        </h1>
      <% } %>

      <% if (locals.blogTitle) { %>
        <h2>
          <%= blogTitle %>
        </h2>
      <% } else { %>
        <h2>
          Blog Title
        </h2>
      <% } %>

      <% if (locals.blogContent) { %>
        <h2>
          <%= blogContent%>
        </h2>
      <% } else { %>
        <p>
          Blog Content
        </p>
      <% } %>`


The issue with your code is the way you are passing the data to ejs:
res.render("blog.ejs",
 { bloggerName: clientName},
 { blogTitle: bloggName },
 { blogContent : blogBody }
)

Remove the curly braces and do this instead:
res.render("blog.ejs",{
  bloggerName: clientName,
  blogTitle: bloggName ,
  blogContent : blogBody 
})

